# How to view the content of postgresql data/base/dboid table

Tags: postgresql

I can see many tables in pg's data/base/dboid directory, some of them i can find in pg_class, but others i cannot find it in pg_class, And i don't what's content of these tables that doesn't exist in pg_class.

The question is how to view these tables content that doesn't exist in pg_class and exist in data/base/dboid.

Comment: First you are not seeing tables you are seeing files that represent several different things, including tables. Second,  you should take a look at [File layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-file-layout.html) to see what those files represent. If you still have questions, then revise the above question.

Comment: These file are ordinary relations, Because they don't have any suffix.

Comment: Without examples of what you are referring to and what you are looking for there is really no answer to the question.